# python seaborn lmplot regplot for y-log scale fit

Tags: python, seaborn

I was wondering why seaborn lmplot and regplot only has the option to do logx. I have a frequent use to linearly fit log(y) ~ x and the Y-axis should always be in log scale to show the correlation (as a convention).

Is this something that can be done in Seaborn?

An option of logy=True would be nice...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply set the y-axis scale to log with:

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
ax.set_yscale('log')  # set_yscale is a function, not a string
```

Comment: edited answer to be more explicit with regplot example

Comment: is it possible to make the x axis in log scale?

Comment: I don't think that this is correct, the fit will still be linear right ? only the axis will be shown in log scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) returned by [regplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html#seaborn.regplot):

```
ax = seaborn.regplot('x', 'y', data)
ax.set(yscale='log')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn doesn’t support this, but you can imitate what it does manually, inserting `np.power(..., 10)` and `np.log10(...)` where appropriate:

```
# create regression plotter object with log’d Y values
rp = sns.regression._RegressionPlotter(x[y>0], np.log10(y[y>0]))
# fit regression model
grid, yhat, err_bands = rp.fit_regression(ax)
# plot regression line with restored Y values
line, = ax.plot(grid, np.power(yhat, 10))
# plot error boundaries
ax.fill_between(
    grid,
    *[np.power(b, 10) for b in err_bands],
    facecolor=line.get_color(),
    alpha=.15,
)
# set axis to log10 scale
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Comment: @eirinn-mackay `ax.set_yscale('log')` does indeed set a log10 scale, not a ln scale. That’s why my answer refers to log10, and that’s why your proposed edit would be wrong.